# Snowflake as backend for high demand API

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My team and I have been using Snowflake daily for the past eight months to transform/enrich our data (with DBT) and make it available in other tools.
While the platform seems great for heavy/long running queries on large datasets and powering analytics tools such as Metabase and Mode, it just doesnt seem to behave well in cases where we need to run really small queries (grab me one line of table A) behind a high demand API, what I mean by that is that SF sometimes takes as much as 100ms or even 300ms on a XLARGE-2XLARGE warehouse to fetch one row in a fairly small table (200k computed records/aggregates), that added up to the network latency makes for a very poor setup  when we want to use it as a backend to power a high demand analytics API.

We've tested multiple setups with Nodejs + Fastify, as well as Python + Fastapi, with connection pooling (10-20-50-100)/without connection pooling (one connection per request, not ideal at all), deployed in same AWS region as our SF deployment, yet we werent able to sustain something close to 50-100 Requests/sec with 1s latency (acceptable), but rather we were only able to get 10-20 Requests/sec with as high as 15-30s latency. Both languages/frameworks behave well on their own, or even with just acquiring/releasing connections, what actually takes the longest and demands a lot of IO is the actual running of queries and waiting for a response. We've yet to try a Golang setup, but it all seems to boil down to how quick Snowflake can return results for such queries.

We'd really like to use Snowflake as database to power a read-only REST API that is expected to have something like 300 requests/second, while trying to have response times in the neighborhood 1s. (But are also ready to accept that it was just not meant for that)

Is anyone using Snowflake in a similar setup? What is the best tool/config to get the most out of Snowflake in such conditions? Should we spin up many servers and hope that we'll get to a decent request rate? Or should we just copy transformed data over to something like Postgres to be able to have better response times?

Comment: Hi Lucas, will you be able to grab the query id, go to query profile and send a snapshot of the query profile.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem with Snowflake ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't claim to be the authoritative answer on this, so people can feel free to correct me, but:

At the end of the day, you're trying to use Snowflake for something it's not optimized for. First, I'm going to run `SELECT 1;` to demonstrate the lower-bound of latency you can ever expect to receive. The result takes 40ms to return. Looking at the breakdown that is 21ms for the query compiler and 19ms to execute it. The compiler is designed to come up with *really smart ways* to process huge complex queries; not to compile small simple queries quickly.

After it has its query plan it must find worker node(s) to execute it on. A virtual warehouse is a collection of worker nodes (servers/cloud VMs), with each VW size being a function of how many worker nodes it has, not necessarily the VM size of each worker (e.g. EC2 instance size). So now the compiled query gets sent off to a different machine to be run where a worker process is spun up. Similar to the query planner, the worker process is not likely optimized to run small queries quickly, so the spin-up and tear-down of that process might be involved (at least relative to say a PostgreSQL worker process).

Putting my `SELECT 1;` example aside in favor of a "real" query, let's talk caching. First, Snowflake does not buffer tables in memory the same way a typical RDBS does. RAM is reserved for computation resources. This makes sense since in traditional usage you're dealing with tables many GBs to TBs in size, so there would be no point since a typical LRU cache would purge that data before it was ever accessed again anyways. This means that a trip to an SSD disk must occur. This is where your performance will start to depend on how homogeneous/heterogeneous your API queries are. If you're lucky you get a cache hit on SSD, otherwise its off to S3 to get your tables. Table files are not redundantly cached across all worker nodes, so while the query planner will make an attempt to schedule a computation on a node most likely to have the needed files in cache, there is no guarantee that a subsequent query will benefit from the cache resulting from the first query if it is assigned to a different worker node. The likeliness of this happening increases if you're firing 100s of queries at the VM/second.

Lastly, and this could be the bulk of your problem but have saved it for last since I am the least certain on it. A small query can run on a subset of the workers in a virtual warehouse. In this case the VH can run concurrent queries with different queries on different nodes. BUT, I am not sure if a given worker node can process more than one query at once. In that case, your concurrency will be limited by the number of nodes in the VH, e.g. a VH with 10 worker nodes can at most run 10 queries in parallel, and what you're seeing are queries piling up at the query planner stage while it waits for worker nodes to free up.

Comment: Brilliant way to demonstrate lower bound latency with `SELECT 1;`!

Answer (score 1):

maybe for this type of workload , the new SF feature **Search Optimization Service** could help you speeding up performances ( https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service.html ).

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @Danny C - that Snowflake is NOT designed for very low (sub-second) latency on single queries.

To demonstrate this consider the following SQL statements (which you can execute yourself):

```html
create or replace table customer as
select *
from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER
limit 500000;

-- Execution time 840ms

create or replace table customer_ten as
select *
from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER
limit 10;

-- Execution time 431ms
```

I just ran this on an XSMALL warehouse and it demonstrates currently (November 2022) Snowflake can copy a HALF MILLION ROWS in 840 milliseconds - but takes 431 ms to copy just 10 rows.

Why is Snowflake so slow compared (for example) to Oracle 11g on premises:
Well - here's what Snowflake has do complete:

1. Compile the query and produce an efficient execution plan (plans are not currently cached as they often lead to a sub-optimal plan being executed on data which has significantly increased in volume)
2. Resume a virtual warehouse (if suspended)
3. Execute the query and write results to cloud storage
4. Synchronously replicate the data to two other data centres (typically a few miles apart)
5. Return OK to the user

Oracle on the other hands needs to:

1. Compile the query (if the query plan is not already cached)
2. Execute the query
3. Write results to local disk

If you REALLY want sub-second query performance on SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on Snowflake - it's coming soon.  Just check out [Snowflake Unistore and Hybrid Tables Explained](https://www.analytics.today/blog/snowflake-unistore-and-hybrid-tables)

Hope this helps.